# How to get value from arraylist to be displayed on jsp using jstl

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I am newbie please help in resolving this,here i need to display data from array list to be displayed in jsp using jstl.
I have created one utill class where it fetch data from database and sets the value in bean
and i added that bean to arraylist like

```
arl.add(devTechBean);
```

and returns the array list to modelandview mylist method where it passes the arraylist to jsp using

```
ModelAndView mnv = 
new ModelAndView("swl_mySoftwareList","mySoftwareList",mySoftwareList);
```

in the jsp i access the array list like

```
${mySoftwareList.assetNumber}
```

(where `assetnumber` is the value i got from bean).
My question is how to access the arraylist in jsp using jstl and i need to know where to map that modelandview mylist method in spring as find that method is not called in jsp.Please help me resolving this.

Answer (score 2):

`mySoftwareList` is an `ArrayList`. SO if you write `${mySoftwareList.assetNumber}`, you're asking the container to call the method `getAssetNumber()` on an object of type `ArrayList`. ArrayList doesn't have such a method.

If you want to call this method on every element of the list, then iterate through the list:

```
<c:forEach var="element" items="${mySoftwareList}>
    ${element.assetNumber}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

If you only have one instance, then simply don't store it in a list and pass it directly to the view:

```
new ModelAndView("swl_mySoftwareList","devTechBean", devTechBean);

${devTechBean.assetNumber}
```

Comment: Thnkx @JBNizet, ya i have iterated the value, but how could i know that the method modelandview mylist() is called in jsp(Mysofwarelist.jsp) which contains all the data in the array list (this jsp(Mysofwarelist.jsp)is loaded on click of link in other jsp(Myhome.jsp)).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: ya i have itereated the arraylist in jsp, but i want to know where to describe that the method modelandview mylist() will be called on click of MySoftware option in other jsp so that when it navigates to (Mysofwarelist.jsp) the values in the array list will get populated.

Comment: you can not call a function using read-only expressions in JSTL, you might be able to do so with deferred expressions but it isn't recommended at all. What you need is to handle that click event with a different controller.